# Generate PDF from HTML contents in Winjs

Tags: html, winjs, jspdf, pdf-reader

I am trying to develop App using [WinJS](https://github.com/winjs/winjs). I want to convert a HTML Content to a PDF file using [JSPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) but I'm getting this error:

> JSPDF is undefined.

I had tried *JSPDF* for *WinJS*.

```
Here is my below code:

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.4.0/jspdf.min.js"></script>
```

Here is my js code:

```
  var doc = new jsPDF();
  doc.text(10, 15, "Hello World from jsPDF.");
  doc.save("jsPDF-Hello_World.pdf");
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what you have done so far, what you have found out througout your own search so far.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow (SO). Always be specific and make your best effort before asking. Please [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions. Also, I recommend you to add some piece of code. Then we can try to fix it or give you an advice.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title of your question to include the links of the libraries you'd mentioned, so more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. I also added blockquotes to the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Please see the [editing help for more information on formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) Good luck!

Comment: Is the uwp app? Could you share [mcve] for us.